# memory sharing when loading .so file in different activities in an android apk

Tags: android, c, shared-libraries

I have two independent Android activities in a single apk.
These two activities both load a source.so file.
My question is that for a global variable `int c;` in the c file from which the .so file was generated, is this `int c` shared between these two activities? 
And will the things be different if it changes to two applications rather than two activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this int c shared between these two activities?

It should be. That variable will be global to your process.

> And will the things be different if it changes to two applications rather than two activities?

Yes, as two applications usually run in separate processes.

Comment: So about the first question, do I still need to load the library twice in each activity, or I just need to load once .

Comment: @henryyao: You load it once, from neither activity, but rather from some other Java class that both activities use.